# Malicious code and PHP

Tags: php

While trying to understand the common security holes, I have a very brief question.
Could this statement ever become true with some clever input?

```
if ($_GET["h"] != $_GET["h"]) {

}
```

(Just using this as an example, not planning on using that exact code :P)

Comment: Probably not, but what is inside the block that makes you ask?

Comment: You can typically trust that whatever web server you're using will pass you the actual values that are in the URL, and not have to worry about them changing. Most of the time, you need to worry about where you're passing those values to. If you pass your input to the database or shell, then you need to worry about what those inputs will do.

Comment: Nothing is inside of that block, just put it there as an example. Point was how much I could trust my GETs. :)

Comment: But something made you ask the question. The reason why that was might be much more interesting to talk about in terms of security.

Comment: Well not entiterly true... One could for instance ask the client for that value (using HTTP). And if the client is asked a second time for that value, simply give a different answer. However `$_GET` and `$_POST` send the data together with the page call to the server in order to reduce bandwidth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I know.

Parameters from `$_GET` are transmitted through the URL like `page.php?h=value`. Once submitted, one cannot change its mind between the first `$_GET` and the second one...

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of how SQL injections work, if it was possible to cut that statement short somehow and ignore parts of it or adding **||true==true** etc.

Comment: Well but SQL injection simply adds another expression who is always equal to `true`. For instance `|| false != true`. In `PHP` the values will first be extracted. And since one cannot carry a boolean expression in a variable, this won't work...

Answer (score 3):

Probably not, but if it's that much of a concern you'd be better off using *not identical* instead of *not equal*.

```
if ('1' != 1) { echo 'true'; } // Does not echo
if (1000 != "10e4") { echo 'true'; } // Does not echo
if ('1' !== 1) { echo 'true'; } // echoes true
```

See more on PHP operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: In what scenario will the same variable reference two different value types?

Comment: None. That statement can never be true.

Comment: My comment wasnt meant to you.